# Is it possible to display trigger error message to Webpage?

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, error-messaging

I have trigger under certain condition, If condition: `false` Error occurs. I should display that error message which occurs in database trigger to `HTML` web page to notify user!

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN        
    IF (NEW.name = NEW.firstname) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'same names error. Insertion canceled';
    END IF;
END
```

**How to display `SET MESSAGE_TEXT=""` to web page? If it's not possible any other ways**

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at [the documentation here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html#signal-condition-information-items).

It says:

> The error values that are accessible after SIGNAL executes are the SQLSTATE value raised by the SIGNAL statement and the MESSAGE_TEXT and MYSQL_ERRNO items. These values are available from the C API:
>
> `mysql_sqlstate()` returns the `SQLSTATE` value.
>
> `mysql_errno()` returns the `MYSQL_ERRNO` value.
>
> `mysql_error()` returns the `MESSAGE_TEXT` value.

Since I'm guessing you're using PHP you can try

```
if (!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO your_table SET name='a', firstname='a'")) {
    printf("Error message: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
```